# Refactor/revert code back to C#5 from C#6

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, teamcity, resharper, c#-6.0

This week we got brand new VS2015 versions installed for our team. So I immediately stared using C#6 syntax all over the place, and then I merged changes to main branch it all failed on TeamCity. It turns out our TeamCity does not support C#6 and we will need new licenses.

For now I will have to rewrite all of my code in previous version (we are talking almost a sprint worth of code 1-2 hours of fixing minimum).

**Is there a way to revert code to previous version of C# (like Resharper or maybe VS2015 supports it) so I wouldn't need to do it manually?**

Comment: What do you mean by "TeamCity does not support C#6"? Can't you install VS2015 on your TeamCity agents?

Comment: Do you not have the previous version of the code in a VCS?

Comment: @sferencik Hi, what is VCS? In regards to TS licenses they are sorting it out ATM.

Comment: By VCS I meant version control system.

Comment: @sferencik Oh, :) Ofc we do we use Mercurial, problem isn't reverting. I have code on my branch with multiple commits where some of them have C#6 code. But when work is completed and tested locally we merge into 'release' branch that will go to regression testing and will be released. This branch gets picked up by Team City and it goes from there so even if I would pull out my stuff from 'release' branch I would still have to fix it before sprint ends... Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To revert to string.Format

regex replace:

`\$\"\{([A-Za-z.]*)\}\"` -> `string.Format("{0}", $1)`

`\$\"\{([A-Za-z. ]*):([0-9.]*)\}\"`  -> `string.Format("{0:$2}", $1)`

`\$\"([A-Za-z. ]*)\{([a-zA-Z]*)\}\"`  -> `string.Format("$1{0}", $2)`

2. To revert [properties regex replace](https://regex101.com/r/zL0kX4/1)

`([a-z]*) ([a-zA-Z?]*) ([A-Za-z]*) => ([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\?\.([a-zA-Z]*);` -> `$1 $2 $3 { get { return $4 == null ? ($2)null : $4.$5; }}`

After this I was left with handful manual changes so I guess it isn't as bad as it originally felt.